# crcn patch error for ns2 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ns2

im very new to ubuntu 10.04, and i have been using it for about 1 month. i have to use ns2 with crcn patch to complete my thesis. the problem occur(within the installation of crcn patch) when i add the following lines at the end of the list (that is, before '$(OBJ_STL)':

```
 wcett/wcett_logs.o wcett/wcett.o \
 wcett/wcett_rtable.o wcett/wcett_rqueue.o \
 mac/macng.o mac/maccon.o \
 mac/macngenhanced.o \
```

. when i invoke the make clean, make depend and make command, its all becoming error. and the ns2 cannot be open, please help me.. thank you in advance

Comment: You need to include the error message.

Comment: hi, thanks for the respon, here is the error when i invoke make clean
rm -f ns nse nsx ns.dyn   gen/version.o gen/ns_tcl.o gen/ptypes.o common/win32.o emulate/net-ip.o emulate/net.o emulate/tap.o emulate/ether.o emulate/internet.o emulate/ping_responder.o emulate/arp.o emulate/icmp.o emulate/net-pcap.o emulate/nat.o emulate/iptap.o emulate/tcptap.o emulate/inet.o common/tclAppInit.o gen/* ns.core core core.ns core.nsx core.nse common/ptypes2tcl common/ptypes2tcl.o

Comment: here the error when i invoke make depend                                   make: Circular emulate/inet.c <- emulate/inet.c dependency dropped.
make: *** No rule to make target `common/tclAppInit.cc', needed by `depend'. Stop.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to implement Cognitive Radio Networks in NS2, I recommend you to use CRAHN package. You can find the code in the following link
https://github.com/abdulla-alali/TFRC-CR/tree/CRAHN